# KML/XML parsing at R not working: whole XML data gets stored in single object and is not being parsed

Tags: r, xml, xml-parsing, kml

I'm guilty of newbieness. Help.

I'vs downloaded data from Google Maps (personalized maps) in KML format and was expecting to transform it into some clean looking table. Boy was I wrong! KML reading functions only were only able to read 5 entries, but it should be dozens more. I opened the file as text and could see the data was there.

Since the non spatial data part is stored in XML, I've had more success in reading the file into R using xmlTreeParse(), but haven't been able to separate the map layers into tables, the data entries into rows and the tags into columns. The layers have different data structures.

I have a single R object with all the XML data (it is already a result of xmlRoot()). Its class is "XMLNode" "RXMLAbstractNode" "XMLAbstractNode" "oldClass". I've searched high and low on youtube and around stackoverflow, and also tried many functions from the XML and xml2 packages, but still can't discover how to split this object by a given node.

All videos just take as granted that after xmlRoot the nodes would appear as different elements inside a list in R but that's not happening. If I use xmlRoot once more, then I loose most of the XML structure and it just becomes a truncated mess of parameters and cdata, like this:

```
            namespace = "", namespaceDefinitions = NULL)), namespace = "", namespaceDefinitions = NULL), Folder = list(name = "Folder", attributes = NULL, children = list(name = list(name = "name", attributes = NULL, children = list(text = list(name = "text", attributes = NULL, children = NULL, namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL, value = "Camada sem título")), namespace = "", namespaceDefinitions = NULL)), namespace = "", namespaceDefinitions = NULL)), namespace = "", namespaceDefinitions = NULL))/>
</>
```

I've read the same document as textline and identified the tags for the layers () and for the entries (), I just can't deal with it as XML.

Also tried xmlToDataFrame but using only the high level object I have it only manages to create a single line data frame where the juicy layers are only thrêe truncated cells (each composed mainly of CDATA, not what I'm looking for).

Oh, and one last problem: it seems **some data is being somewhat modified without reason**. I've identified one instance where the value changed from "1.2711053" to "1.2711053e7" in the nodes, but remained correct in the CDATA. I have no clue why.

Any light at this dark hour will be much appreciated.

Comment: Without (a link to) an actual example file, there is no way for anyone to help you here. We cannot explore what might be going on with the parsing if we cannot test and verify it ourselves. There are just too many possibilities. Please make your question reproducible.